# iOS Xcode How to persist data with custom objects containing custom objects?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

Android developer and iOS newb here.  I have an app I'm migrating to iOS.  I'm learning Xcode and Swift at the same time so be gentle please! :)

My question is I simply want to save/retrieve a class such as below (in Java):

```
public class CardDeck implements Parcelable{

  private ArrayList<Profile> cards;

  private int location;

  public CardDeck(){
    this.cards = new ArrayList<>();
    this.location = 0;
    //this.numCards = 0;
  }

  public CardDeck(ArrayList<Profile> cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
    this.location = 0;
    //this.numCards = cards.size();
  }

  protected CardDeck(Parcel in) {
    cards = in.createTypedArrayList(Profile.CREATOR);
    //numCards = in.readInt();
    location = in.readInt();
  }
}
```

I would like to save/retrieve a CardDeck object that contains an Array of Profiles.  My initial readings makes me think you cannot do this with either UserDefaults or NSCoding because plist files cannot contain a custom data type like Profile.  Did I get that right?  UserDefaults are for standard data types (bool, int, String, etc.) and NSCoding can handle a custom object such as CardDeck BUT CardDeck can only have members that are standard data types.

How would you pros handle my problem?  Core Data?

I handled this in Android by using `SharedPreferences` and `Gson.toJson(cardDeck)`.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreData is an ORM built on top of SQLLite. It sounds like it might be overkill for what you want.

You could just declare your classes Codable:

class CardDeck : Codable
{
}

Then just use JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder to encode and decode them to Data objects which can be converted to String and then stored in a file or user preferences. Any custom types in CardDeck will also need to be JSONCodeable.

JSONCodeable is a protocol (i.e. Interface in Java terms) and can be implemented as an extension on an existing class (can't do this in Java, sort of can in C#).

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  I'll look into JSONCodable.  Sounds like exactly what I need.  So grateful.  Thanks again.  Found it on cocoapods.

Comment: Oh!  I see now that you don't have to use the Pod.  You can use JSONEncoder/decoder is a part of the Codable interface in Swift 4.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. JSONCodable is a Swift 4 feature.